# edit file using by taking user input in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, io

i want to edit email id and phone number by taking user input but i am unable to that through this what i am doing wrong in this code help.

file.txt

```
Jon Snow 996452544 Jon@gmail
Robb 885546694 Robb@gmail
Robert 896756885 Robert@gmail
```

code

```
 def editContact():
    obj2 = open("address.txt","r")  
    output = []

    old_email=raw_input("Enter old email address : ")               
    new_email=raw_input("Enter new email address : ")
    s = re.sub(old_email, new_email, obj2)     

    obj1 = open("address.txt","w")
    obj1.writelines(s)
```

Comment: Please correct your indentation.

Comment: no issue in indentation code is working Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./addressBookpy.py", line 72, in <module>
    editContact()
  File "./addressBookpy.py", line 54, in editContact
    s = re.sub(old_email, new_email, obj2)     
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/re.py", line 151, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, 0).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
This error i am geting

Comment: The indentation issue is trying to read the code and answer your question.  Show the error in your question, not in a comment.

Comment: Your error is because the third parameter of `re.sub` should be a string not a file object.

Comment: Note that opening a file with write access will truncate the file to zero bytes destroying existing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue you are having is :

```
s = re.sub(old_email, new_email, obj2)
```

obj2 here is a file obj, read the file using obj2.read()

then you will be able to replace.

Answer (score 1):

```
abc=obj2.read()
s = re.sub(old_email, new_email, abc)
```